# How to ignore some input layer, while predicting, in a keras model trained with multiple input layers?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, disabled-input

I'm working with neural networks and I've implemented the following architecture using `keras` with `tensorflow` backend:

[image]

For training, I'll give some labels in the layer `labels_vector`, this vector can have `int32` values (ie: 0 could be a label). For the testing phase, I need to just ignore this input layer, if I set it to `0` results could be wrong since I've trained with labels that can be equal to `0` vector. Is there a way to simply ignore or disable this layer on the prediction phase?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is probably possible to achieve what you're trying to do by redesigning your network. but you can't just say to Keras to ignore an Input Layer, your output depends on it.

Some advices though: 1. Do not use scalars as categorical labels (use one-hot encoding)  2. Labels should not be part of the inputs as it's a value you want to predict.

Comment: Thanks a lot @GhilasBELHADJ, I prefer the 1st though, because, in our model, we would like to give additional features: the layer 'labels_vector' in fact represent some computed features, in addition to the labels that will be used for training. So, I think I would like to try the one hot encoding of the features. Thanks again.

Comment: I you're using a one-hot encoding, set a custom value to represent a none input for your `labels_vector` ... the network will learn to ignore it, if it has no sens.

Comment: okay !!! nice idea ! thanks again, thans a lot :)

Comment: @GhilasBELHADJ, would you like to make your comments as a response to this question, please? since I've got the needed help, I want to validate your response to get this issue solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to ignore some input layer ?

You **can't**. Keras cannot just ignore an input layer as the output depends on it.

One solution to get nearly what you want is to define a custom label in your training data to be the null value. Your network will learn to *ignore* it if it feels that it is not an important feature.

If `labels_vector` is a vector of categorical labels, use *one-hot encoding* instead of *integer encoding*. integer encoding assumes that there is a natural ordered relationship between each label which is wrong.

Comment: may I ask how it was solved @BelkacemThiziri ? Could you post it as a separate answer?