# Difficulty in Connecting Layers with Keras: Graph Disconnected

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning

I am trying to build a NN model for my Policy Gradient (deep reinforcement learning) agent by using Keras Functional API. What I intend to do is to mask invalid actions by reducing their probability distribution to zero in the logit layer:

```py
def __build_policy_network(self):
    inputs = keras.layers.Input(shape=(self.input_dim,))
    advantages = keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,))
    valid_actions = keras.layers.Input(shape=(3,))
    dense_1 = keras.layers.Dense(units=self.fc1_size, activation="relu", kernel_initializer="he_uniform")(inputs)
    dense_2 = keras.layers.Dense(units=self.fc2_size, activation="relu", kernel_initializer="he_uniform")(dense_1)
    probs_logits = keras.layers.Dense(units=self.nb_actions, activation='softmax')(dense_2)
    masked_probs = keras.layers.Multiply()([probs_logits, valid_actions])
    probs = keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x / keras.backend.sum(x, axis=1))(masked_probs)
    
       def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
           out = keras.backend.clip(y_pred, 1e-8, 1 - 1e-8)
           log_lik = y_true * keras.backend.log(out)
           return keras.backend.sum(-log_lik * advantages)
    
     policy = keras.models.Model([inputs, advantages], [probs])
     policy.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=self.alpha), loss=custom_loss)
     predict = keras.models.Model([inputs, valid_actions], [probs])
     return policy, predict
```

However, I run into the infamous error `ValueError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor Tensor("input_3:0", shape=(None, 3), dtype=float32) at layer "multiply".` When I comment out either of the `advantages` or `valid_actions` input layers (and of course, removing their corresponding lines) I can successfully run the code. I should mention that `valid_actions` input layer is only passed to mask invalid probabilities and is not required for loss calculation.

I really appreciate it if someone can help me with this.

Thanks in advance for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot to [MarcoCerliani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10375049/marco-cerliani) for his time and follow-ups, I succeeded to find a working solution to my problem finally. The mistake was that I modified the `probs` output layer which is required for loss calculation with the `valid_actions` input layer which is indeed only required for the `predict` model. As stated by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51097686/3156071):

> Keras cannot just ignore an input layer as the output depends on it.

all I need to do is pass `probs_logits` (the unmodified output layer by the `valid_actions` layer) to the `policy model` for loss calculation and pass the `probs` output layer (manipulated by the `valid actions` layer) to `predict model`:

```
def __build_policy_network(self):

 // previous lines of code left unchanged

 policy = keras.models.Model([inputs, advantages], [probs_logits])
 policy.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=self.alpha), loss=custom_loss)
 predict = keras.models.Model([inputs, valid_actions], [probs])
 return policy, predict
```

Answer (score 2):

Your loss involves also `advantages` so you need to pass it inside the loss. You can do it with `.add_loss`.

`policy` model needs also `valid_actions` as input to produce `probs`.

`predict` model seems ok and can be used at inference time.

Here the full example with `.add_loss`.

```
inputs = keras.layers.Input(shape=(30,))
advantages = keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,))
valid_actions = keras.layers.Input(shape=(3,))
true = keras.layers.Input(shape=(3,))
dense_1 = keras.layers.Dense(units=64, activation="relu", kernel_initializer="he_uniform")(inputs)
dense_2 = keras.layers.Dense(units=32, activation="relu", kernel_initializer="he_uniform")(dense_1)
probs_logits = keras.layers.Dense(units=3, activation='softmax')(dense_2)
masked_probs = keras.layers.Multiply()([probs_logits, valid_actions])
probs = keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x / keras.backend.sum(x, axis=1))(masked_probs)

def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred, advantages):
    out = keras.backend.clip(y_pred, 1e-8, 1 - 1e-8)
    log_lik = y_true * keras.backend.log(out)
    return keras.backend.sum(-log_lik * advantages)

policy = keras.models.Model([inputs, advantages, valid_actions, true], [probs])
policy.add_loss( custom_loss(true, probs, advantages) )
policy.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001), loss=None)
predict = keras.models.Model([inputs, valid_actions], [probs])
```